# Add Custom Fields to Magento CMS Page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've been trying to add custom fields to Magento's CMS page. I've followed two different guides online and in both cases, it doesn't display the box even after logging out, clearing cache, and even disabling cache.

Is there a different way to do this on 1.7?

I've followed these guides:
http://blog.flexishore.com/2011/08/add-custom-field-to-cms-page/
http://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-custom-attribute-to-a-cms-page/

Thank you!

Comment: Have you find a solution for this?